# Laravel4 custom validation does not work in some situation

Tags: php, laravel-4

I write a custom validation rule to check if the input field is a character with 6 numbers.

Below is the code

```
Validator::extend('patterncheck', function($filed, $value, $parameter) {
    $pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}$/';

    return preg_match($pattern, $value);
});

$messages = array(
    'patterncheck' => 'The :attribute is not correct'
);

$credential = array(
    'country' => $Invent['country'],
    'patternnum' => $Invent['pattern-num']
);

$rules = array (
    'country' => 'required',
    'patternnum' => 'alpha_num|required|max:7|min:7|patterncheck'
);

$validate = Validator::make($credential, $rules, $messages);


if($validate->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validate);
} else {
    return Redirect::back()->with('msg', 'correct');
}
```

In the redirect page, show error message or correct message

```
<span>
@if ($errors->has('patternnum'))
    @foreach ($errors->get('patternnum') as $errormsg)
        {{{$errormsg}}}
    @endforeach
@else
    {{{Session::get('msg')}}}
@endif
</span>
```

If i input wrong strings such as abc1234, ww11111, it works correctly and shows the error message.
But if input strings such as w123456, a232323 that should match the pattern, it does not work, the redirected page does not display "correct" message.

Then I rewrite the code as below, and then input w123456, a232323, the redirected page shows "incorrect" message that means it still goes to $validate->fails() condition. But if it still goes to failed condition, why the redirected page does not display error message in the above code?

```
if($validate->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->with('msg', 'incorrect');
}
```

what is the problem? Is it because the $pattern value is wrong?

Comment: how you are echoing the message?

Comment: add the debugbar to your project. and see what the session holds. i have a feeling the seesion is getting lost somewhere.

Comment: @itachi I have not used a debugbar yet, is there any recommendation  for good debugbar?

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar